# How to create a play against the computer function to my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

First let me say, thank you for any help/advice I may receive. I am truly grateful.
I've built a tic-tac-toe app in react (mostly from youtube). It currently only works as a local multiplayer game. I would like to add an option for the player to choose between local multiplayer, or against AI. The ai doesn't need to be advanced, simply picking a random available space will do fine.

My Game.js file looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Board from './Board';

export default class Game extends Component {
     constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state= {
            xIsNext: true,
            stepNumber: 0,
            history: [
                { squares: Array(9).fill(null) }
            ]
        }
    }
    jumpTo(step){
        this.setState({
            stepNumber: step,
            xIsNext: (step%2)===0
        })

    }



    handleClick(i) {
        const history = this.state.history.slice(0,this.state.stepNumber+1);
        const current = history[history.length-1];
        const squares = current.squares.slice();
        const winner = calculateWinner(squares);
        //stops player from picking a chosen square
        if(winner || squares[i]){
            return;
        }
        squares[i] = this.state.xIsNext?'X':'0';
        this.setState({
            history: history.concat({
                squares: squares
            }),
            xIsNext: !this.state.xIsNext,
            stepNumber: history.length
        });
    }
    render() {
        const history = this.state.history;
        const current = history[this.state.stepNumber];
        const winner= calculateWinner(current.squares);
        const moves= history.map((step, move)=>{
            const desc = move? 'Go to #' + move:'Choose a square to begin the game';
            return (
                <li key={move}>
                    <button onClick={()=>{this.jumpTo(move)}}>
                            {desc}
                    </button>
                </li>
            )
        });
        let status;
        if(winner){
            status = 'Winner is ' + winner
        } else{
            status = 'Next Player is ' + (this.state.xIsNext?'X':'0');
        }



        return (
            <div className="game">
                <div className="game-board">
                    <Board onClick={(i)=>this.handleClick(i)}
                    squares={current.squares} />
                </div>
                    <div>{status}</div>
                    <ul>{moves}</ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
//sets win condition
function calculateWinner(squares){
    const lines = [
        [0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [6, 7, 8],
        [0, 3, 6],
        [1, 4, 7],
        [2, 5, 8],
        [0, 4, 8],
        [2, 4, 6]
    ];
    for(let i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
        const [a,b,c] = lines[i];
        if(squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[b] === squares[c]){
         return squares [a];
        }
    }

   return null;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you aren't looking for a perfect AI, but if you want to try, you can create one by building a min-max tree of all the game states. Something like this: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-make-your-tic-tac-toe-game-unbeatable-by-using-the-minimax-algorithm-9d690bad4b37/  or  this:  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimax-algorithm-in-game-theory-set-3-tic-tac-toe-ai-finding-optimal-move/ or this: https://www.neverstopbuilding.com/blog/minimax

Comment: no im looking for a simple ui that just picks a random unoccupied square, not trying to have the computer beat me haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an optional param to `handleClick()`, let's call it `computerIsGoing`. At the end of `handleClick()`, add this code:

```
if ( ! computerIsGoing ) {
    this.computersTurn()
}
```

The `computersTurn()` function would look something like this (pseudocode):

```
function computerIsGoing() {
    // Look at all the squares, find all the ones not yet filled in, pick a random one (e.g. 5)
    let n = 5; // Assume
    this.handleClick( n, true );
}
```

This will cause the `computersTurn()` function to run after every time the user clicks a square.